# Is there a MapReduce library for Lua?

Tags: lua, mapreduce

Is there a **MapReduce** library for [**Lua**](http://www.lua.org/)?

*(I obviously can't find one)*

Answer (score 2):

[Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

[lua-mapreduc](https://github.com/rohitjoshi/lua-mapreduce)e is a map-reduce implementation in lua.

Here is a wiki page: https://github.com/rohitjoshi/lua-mapreduce/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Penlight looks good.

[Underscore.lua](http://mirven.github.com/underscore.lua/) is a Lua version of underscore.js, which has map/reduce.

Comment: Having a `map` and a `reduce` function isn't the same thing as MapReduce.  The "map" step of MapReduce isn't the `map` function of functional programming.  The "reduce" step of MapReduce isn't the `reduce` function of functional programming either.  [It's a bit of a slog to read this](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=7,650,331.PN.&OS=PN/7,650,331&RS=PN/7,650,331 "System and method for efficient large-scale data processing") but you'll see what I mean when you do.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pakozm/lua-mapreduce

It differs from https://github.com/rohitjoshi/lua-mapreduce in the basis of the communication between the processes. In order to allow fault tolerancy, and to reduce the communication protocol complexity, this implementation relies on mongoDB. So, all the data is stored at auxiliary mongoDB collections.